# Should not allow any numbers and special characters other than space

Tags: html

The text “Enter User Name” should be displayed by default in the text box. When the user starts entering the name, this text should disappear, is a mandatory field, should be validated. It should not allow any numbers and special characters other than space. Do not use javascript, use HTML 5 features.

```
<input type="text name="username" placeholder="Enter User Name pattern="[A-Za-z\s]" required/>
```

but it shows error as 
"Must have used the HTML Component with the name 'username' with appropriate constraints"

Comment: For starters, your HTML isn't valid.  You're missing some quote marks on your attributes.

Comment: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter User Name"  pattern="[A-Za-z\s]" required /> quotes not properly placed

Answer (score 2):

Try It ,

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label>Enter User Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter User Name" pattern="[A-Za-z\s]{0,50}" required title="Pleace Enter Alphabet Characters Only"/><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```